# Can't install libstdc++

Tags: package-management, c++, libraries

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04, here what I've got:

```
 ...
      libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-arm64-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross but 4.8.4-1ubuntu15cross0.15 is to be installed
      libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-armel-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross but 4.7.4-2ubuntu1cross1.86 is to be installed
      libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-armhf-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross but 4.7.4-2ubuntu1cross1.86 is to be installed
                                       Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross but 4.8.4-1ubuntu10cross0.15 is to be installed
      libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-powerpc-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross but 4.8.4-1ubuntu10cross0.18 is to be installed
      libstdc++6-4.9-dbg-ppc64el-cross : Conflicts: libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-ppc64el-cross but 4.8.4-1ubuntu10cross0.7 is to be installed
     E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: what was your `apt-get` command you used?

Comment: @Aizuddin Azli sudo apt-get install libstdc++

Comment: Answer by @DevRobot should solve your issue. Dont forget to marked it as Answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no package with name `libstdc++`  see [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=wily&searchon=names&keywords=libstdc%2B%2B).  i think you are looking for `libstdc++6`.so install using

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

or
if you looking for another library that is missing in your system then search which package have that library and install or extract that package and copy library directly .